# Creating Facebook like button using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create [Facebook Like button][1] using bootstrap. Here is my code. The code works fine on my computer but not on JSFiddle. Please guide me. Thanks.

```
 <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like</button>
```

Comment: where is the fiddle? you can share it atleast.

Answer (score 2):

```
Just add bootstrap.css
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up">Like</i> </button>
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be an image before the text like because I have added `fa-thumbs-up` class?

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't there be an image before the text like because I have added
>   fa-thumbs-up class?

Do you have the Font awesome .js referenced?

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/xxxxxx.js"></script>
```